# Настой (настойка) из ромашки, настой (настойка) на ромашке или настой (настойка) ромашки?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Правомерны ли каждый из этих вариантов?

Answer (score 1):

Кроме того, что настойка - это разговорный вариант слова настой (спиртовая лекарственная форма), слово настойка означает алкогольный напиток. И употребление далее предлога, зависит, по-моему, от значения слова.  Если это алкогольный напиток - то настойка на ромашке (как на травах). Если важно, что это лекарство - то настойка ромашки. Поэтому на аптечных препаратах именно так и написано. А водка может быть "на кедровых орешках", например. Что касается предлога ИЗ, то на мой взгляд, это разговорный вариант предлога НА. Все-таки **настаивать на чем**, а не **из чего**...

Comment: Согласна: если это алкоголь, то "настаивать на чем". Но если это лекарственный, водный экстракт какого-л. вещества, растения, то можно сказать и "настой из (хвои)", например, как в статье "Настой" на gramota.ru:

НАСТОЙ, -я; м.
Лекарственный, водный экстракт какого-л. вещества, растения. Хвойный, ромашковый н. Н. на травах. Н. липы, ревеня. Сделать н. из хвои.

Может, и не стоит ограничиваться минимумом правильных вариантов, а употреблять и так, и эдак. А то чем больше ограничений - тем больше ошибок...

Answer (score 0):

Слово **настойка** в значении 'лекарственный спиртовой экстракт какого-л. вещества, растения' является разговорным, слово **настой** в том же значении - общеупотребительным. 
Насчет предложного падежа с предлогом **на** (*настой на ромашке*) лично у меня возникает сомнение, немного режет слух, хотя *настой на травах* - общеупотребительное словосочетание. Думаю, из остальных вариантов (*настой из ромашки, настой ромашки, ромашковый настой*) можно выбрать любой.